# Remove Day Name from String T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a string format of a date in the this form Thursday, September 13, 2018. I would like to remove "Thursday" so I can convert the string to a date type and do a date comparison. Does anyone know how to remove a weekday name in a string using T-SQL?

Comment: You could do `SELECT TRY_PARSE('Thursday, September 13, 2018' AS date USING 'en-GB')`

Answer (score 1):

If there is **always** white space (`' '`) after the day name/prior to date, you could use `CHARINDEX` and `STUFF`:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date,STUFF(V.YourString,1,CHARINDEX(' ',V.YourString),''))
FROM (VALUES('Thursday, September 13, 2018'))V(YourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(
    DATE, 
    Substring(
      'Thursday, September 13, 2018', 
      Patindex(
        '%day%', 'Thursday, September 13, 2018'
      ) + 5, 
      Len('Thursday, September 13, 2018')
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question explain your code. This improves answer value long term.